# Campaign Creator loading problem

Tags: campaigncreator

I'm researching the Campaign Creator functionality introduced in Sitecore 8.1 and have been able to successfully create campaigns and associate with content items.

The issue I'm experiencing is that the campaign creator seems to endlessly load on access once a campaign has been created, thus preventing me from being able to edit the campaign I've just created.

Has anyone made use of the Campaign Creator yet who could shine light on my problem ?

I'm receiving the following error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

The request is hitting `/sitecore/api/ssc/CampaignManagement/Campaign?pageSize=10&pa‌​geIndex=0&payLoad=fu‌​ll&language=en&name=‌​&startDate=&endDate=‌​&classifications=&sc‌​_lang=en` which is responding with a JSON string of:

```js
{"Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

Requesting that URL directly results in a 403 (Forbidden) response. Do I need to do something to allow Sitecore to communicate with it's own API?

Comment: A little more information after further digging. I'm receiving the following error in the console

_Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)_

The request is hitting 

/sitecore/api/ssc/CampaignManagement/Campaign?pageSize=10&pageIndex=0&payLoad=full&language=en&name=&startDate=&endDate=&classifications=&sc_lang=en

which is responding with a JSON string of

{"Message":"An error has occurred."}

Comment: Further further information. Requesting that URL directly results in a 403 (Forbidden) response. Do I need to do something to allow Sitecore to communicate with it's own API ?

Comment: please share your log with us. I have faced the same kind of problems; Changes are big that you have updated a Microsoft WebAPI/MVC assembly, Newtonsoft.JSON or another assembly that has been delivered with Sitecore by installing a custom package. Updating one of those assemblies to a newer version might break sitecore.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that this came down to an issue with missing configuration files.

I compared my instance against a default installation and noticed the discrepancy.

I was missing Sitecore.Marketing.Search.config

Thanks for your comments

Comment: What was the discrepancy? Please describe it in detail if you're going to leave an answer.

Comment: edited to conform as above

Answer (score 2):

We had exactly the same problem. After rebuild of **sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master** and **sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master** indexes it's fully functional again.

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Glass Mapper and Windsor for dependency injection you need to do something like this:

```cs
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Sitecore.Speak.Client").BasedOn<Controller>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Sitecore.ListManagement.Services").BasedOn<ContactListController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Sitecore.Marketing.Campaigns.Services").BasedOn<CampaignController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Sitecore.Marketing.Campaigns.Services").BasedOn<ClassificationsController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Sitecore.ContentTesting").BasedOn<TestOutcomesController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("Sitecore.ContentTesting").BasedOn<ActivityController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Here is a thread on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416906/no-component-for-supporting-the-service-sitecore-mvc-controllers-sitecorecontrol

Comment: although this MAY be an answer, it's a pure speculation. I think more information is needed to determine what the rootcause is and then a solution should be supplied.